# Как получить исключение при нарушении прав доступа при чтении

Tags: c++

Могу-ли я как-то получить искючение `нарушение прав доступа при чтении` в `try\catch` что-бы в каждом месте где мне выдаёт исключение я прописывал необходимые мне условия например что бы программа не просто вылетала а выдавала `return 0;` Я пробовал использовать

```
int main()
{
    try 
    {
        my code...
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Но оно не сработало есть ли иные варианты?

Comment: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении не является С++ исключением и его средствами не перехватывается. А вообще вам следует исправлять ошибки в своем коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это совершенно разные исключения, просто названы одним словом, что и сбивает с толку :),  так что одни в другие в общем случае не преобразуются.

Но в Visual C++ имеется такая возможность - использовать ключ компилятора [`/EHa`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=vs-2019):

```
/EHa включить C++ EH (с исключениями SEH)
```

но я бы не очень рекомендовал это делать...

Подробнее о SEH в Visual C++ можно почитать [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=vs-2019).